# why do i get this warning with gcc-arm-none-eabi

Tags: c, arm, constants, gcc-warning

I'm getting the below warning:

> /path/to/project/src/my_main.c:24:36: warning: pointer targets in initialization of 'const uint8_t *' {aka 'const unsigned char *'} from 'char *' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]

for the following line:

```
const uint8_t* REQUPDATE_WARNING = "{\"id\":\"warning\",\"value\":\"mcu_upd\"}\n";
```

Where `uint8_t` is:

```
(stdint.h):
#ifndef _UINT8_T_DECLARED
typedef __uint8_t uint8_t ;
#define _UINT8_T_DECLARED

(_default_types.h)
#ifdef __UINT8_TYPE__
typedef __UINT8_TYPE__ __uint8_t;
#else
typedef unsigned __INT8_TYPE__ __uint8_t;
#endif
```

Why do I get this warning and how can I remove it?

Comment: Representing a string with an `uint8_t *` doesn't make much sense. Why do you need that instead of `const char *`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string literals are arrays of chars which decay to `char *`

You need to add the cast to suppress the warning

```
const uint8_t* REQUPDATE_WARNING = (uint8_t *)"{\"id\":\"warning\",\"value\":\"mcu_upd\"}\n";
```